# Adding new data to collection in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, fetch

I've fetched a [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) collection, and now I want to fetch another data bulk, and *add* it to the existing collection. I've tried adding `add: true` to the `fetch` command, yet nothing seems to add. The model data is replaced with the new data.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing out on a basic issue. Help? Thanks.

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your code. `fetch({add:true})` should do it.

Comment: how about showing us some code, we can give you ideas but we can make more realistic remarks if we see what's happening.

Comment: I agree with Sander and kennis: show some code. However, a general solution (the one I used) is to create a collection inside the collection (myDumpColl = new backboneCollectionDeclaredBefore), that you use as a temp collection to make your fetch-add-copy operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One untested possibility :

```
people.reset( people.toArray().concat( newPeople));
```

But this isn't the backbone way. I would use Kennis' suggestion

```
fetch( {add:true});
```

Do you have any event handlers resetting the collection?